# Column Width vs Hidden Column

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any difference between hiding a column and setting its width to **0**.  That is are:

```
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 0
```

and

```
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

completely equivalent ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my test code, they are completely equivalent

```
Sub TestHidden()

  ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 0

  If ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Hidden = True Then
    MsgBox "Column is hidden"
  End If


  ActiveSheet.Columns(3).Hidden = True
  MsgBox "Col 3 width:" & ActiveSheet.Columns(3).ColumnWidth

End Sub
```

Paste it into Sheet1's VBA page to run it.

Comment: its actually  0  <= .RowHeight <= 0.0749 which is the same as hidden just to be precise!

Comment: @StevenMartin Can you provide a reference for this? I can have a hidden column with .RowHeight = 15.

Comment: Oops were talking about Columns not Rows ,  with Columns its `0 <= .ColumnWidth <= 0.0416` that is the same as hidden.

Comment: @StevenMartin  You comments ar extremely interesting.........consider posting an answer.

Comment: @StevenMartin yes, please post an answer. I'd be happy to upvote as I didn't know that there was any leeway in what was acceptable as a hidden width.

Comment: @StevenMartin - I believe that you may find that the actual numbers determining the minimum are a bit subjective depending on the default font and possibly the resolution that the computer is running under. The 0.0416 you are referring to is the maximum where Excel will round down to zero on your system configuration. FWIW, on my laptop this is ~0.027. If I set the column width to that and then check the column width, it reports as zero, not 0.027. If I try 0.028, it will register a column width of 0.06. [Description of how column widths are determined in Excel](http://tinyurl.com/nglfq5c)

Answer (score 2):

While your question was primarily targeted at column widths and hidden status, I would point out that rows made non-visible with a filter report a row height of zero and a true `.Hidden` attribute. Subsequently hiding some additioanl rows then clearing the filter will make all of the rows visible. In other words, clearing the `.AutoFilter` overrides the rows you manually hid.

[image: Row Filtering and Hidden]

Given the above sample data, run the following macro. It will filter out two of the data rows then hide the ones left visible. Finally, it will clear the AutoFilter.

```
Sub AutoFilter_is_Hidden()
    Dim r As Long
    With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        If .AutoFilter Then .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=0
        For r = 2 To 5
            Debug.Print "Row " & r & " hidden: " & .Rows(r).Hidden & " - " & .Rows(r).RowHeight
        Next r
        With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
        For r = 2 To 5
            Debug.Print "Row " & r & " hidden: " & .Rows(r).Hidden & " - " & .Rows(r).RowHeight
        Next r
        .AutoFilter
        For r = 2 To 5
            Debug.Print "Row " & r & " hidden: " & .Rows(r).Hidden & " - " & .Rows(r).RowHeight
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Here are the results from the Immediate window, commented for clarity.

```
' column D filtered for 0
Row 2 hidden: True - 0
Row 3 hidden: False - 14.5
Row 4 hidden: True - 0
Row 5 hidden: False - 14.5
' with filter still active, visible cells hidden
Row 2 hidden: True - 0
Row 3 hidden: True - 0
Row 4 hidden: True - 0
Row 5 hidden: True - 0
' Autofilter removed
Row 2 hidden: False - 14.5
Row 3 hidden: False - 14.5
Row 4 hidden: False - 14.5
Row 5 hidden: False - 14.5
```

You end up with what you started with, not two rows hidden.

So it would appear that not only is a RowHeight/ColumnWidth of zero indistinguishable from a true Hidden attribute but the nature of an Autofilter is also exactly the same; it does not distinguish between its own hidden rows and rows that you have hidden by some other method. If there was any difference, then it would not unhide the rows that were hidden by an alternate method when its filter was cleared.

Answer (score 1):

I have Excel-2013 that `ColumnWidth` maximum value to have a hidden column is `3.84615384615385E-02`

As I try :

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 3.84615384615385E-02
```

> Columns(2) is Hidden.

And

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 3.84615384615386E-02
```

> Columns(2) is Not Hidden.